# How to replace dynamic_sidebar in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm not a PHP developer and I don't understand the language at all. However, I'm asked to modify a PHP page. It's a WordPress blog. It has a block of code:

```
            <div>
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'pre-footer-1' ); ?>
            </div>
```

When I load the page, I can see a sidebar added to a footer. I don't want the sidebar. I just want the information comes out fro the index 'pre-footer-1'. How should I modify the code to make it work? I tried:

```
            <div>
                <?php echo( 'pre-footer-1' ); ?>
            </div>
```

Sorry, I just don't know how to simply show the content without the dynamic sidebar.

EDITED:

It's a Wordpress theme. The theme has a pre-footer that I can modify in the theme setting. The theme always show a sidebar on a pre-footer. It's not a bug, it's the way how the theme is designed. However, I don't like it and would like to get rid of the sidebar. I still want to show the footer just not the sidebar. I don't know php and would like a simple solution to modify the PHP code such that the sidebar is gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)? Something like:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-id');
    $sidebar = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
?>
```

This should get you the contents of the sidebar. Just `echo` the `$sidebar` where you need it.